# Bad pad corrupt error in ANDROID encrypted in Java project

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I am ecrypting the data in java(Java project using AES) and want to decrypt the data in android but I am getting bad pad corrupt error.If same is run on java project its woking.Java project and android code is below:

**Java Side code(Java Project):**

```
enter code here

public static void main(String[] args)  {
//Same password used in android
        String masterpassword ="test";
        String crypto =  encrypt(masterpassword, "XYZ");

}






 public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
            System.out.println(rawKey);
            byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
           return Base64.encode(result);
         //   return toHex(result);
        }




 private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(seed);
            kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
            return raw;
        }




    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }
```

**Android Side Code:**
    *

```
public void onDecrypt(View view){
System.out.println("onDecrypt ");
        String param = "w7ayjByx5I0yrX2tT8gj4w==";//Encrypted data
        String masterpassword ="test";
        try {
            String res = decrypt(masterpassword, param);
}
}
```

*

```
 public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
            byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
            System.out.println(rawKey);
          //  byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
            byte[] enc = Base64.decode(encrypted);
            byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
            return new String(result);
        }

  private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            sr.setSeed(seed);
            kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
            return raw;
        }


  private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
            return decrypted;
        }
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one mistake. In these lines ...

Java (encrypt side)

```
        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
```

Android(decrypt side):

```
        return new String(result);
```

... you are using the default platform character set encoding. Never do that, always explicitly specify the charset encoding. Just use "UTF-8" which is universal and, except perhaps for some Asian languages, optimally space efficient. So, use the correct [getBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) method and [String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor.

I also notice you are using a SecureRandom instance to expand a seed. This is a pretty non-standard way of doing this. It might work but it is a bad idea.

Comment: Hi thanks.You are suggesting SecureRandom is not standard way to generate key .then what do you suggest to generate a symmetric key.

Comment: I have made changes as you suggested still i am not able to decrypt at android side.
Java (encrypt side)

        byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Android(decrypt side):

        return new String(result,"UTF-8");